# Kubernetes workload for stateful application but no need of persistent disk

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-statefulset, kubernetes-deployment

I am having a stateful application - I am keeping data in user's sessions (basically data in `HttpSession` object) - but I do not have any requirement to write anything to persistent disk.

From what I have read so far - StatefulSet workloads are meant for stateful applications, but my understanding so far is that even though my application is a stateful application but Deployment workloads can also suffice my requirement because I do not want to write anything to persistent disks.

However, one point I am not sure about is that suppose I use Deployment workload and a lot of user data is present in my `HttpSession` object, now due to some reason Kubernetes restarts my Pod then of course all that user session data will be lost. So, my question are following:

- Does StatefulSet handles this situation any better than Deployment workload?
- So, only difference between Deployment workload and StatefulSet workload is about absence/presence of persistent disk or there is something to do with application session management as well in case of StatefulSet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does StatefulSet handles this situation any better than Deployment workload?

No. Neither `Deployment` nor `StatefulSet` will preserve memory contents. To preserve session information, you'll need to store it somewhere. One common approach is to use [Redis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redis).

> So, only difference between Deployment workload and StatefulSet workload is about absence/presence of persistent disk or there is something to do with application session management as well in case of StatefulSet?

No, there are other differences:

- StatefulSets create (and re-create) deterministic, consistent pod names (identifiers).
- StatefulSets, are deployed, scaled, and updated **one by one** in a deterministic, consistent order. The next pod will be created only after the previous one reached the `Running` state.

Additionally, it's worth mentioning that persistent disks can be attached to pods that aren't part of a `StatefulSet`. It's just that it's convenient to have disks always be attached to a pod with a consistent id. For instance if you have pods running a replicated database, you can use StatefulSets to ensure that the master replica's disk is always attached to pod #1.

Edit:

[Link to official documentation about StatefulSets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/)

From the documentation:

> Like a Deployment, a StatefulSet manages Pods that are based on an
> identical container spec. Unlike a Deployment, a StatefulSet maintains
> a sticky identity for each of their Pods. These pods are created from
> the same spec, but are not interchangeable: each has a persistent
> identifier that it maintains across any rescheduling.

...

> StatefulSets are valuable for applications that require one or more of
> the following.
>
> - Stable, unique network identifiers.
> - Stable, persistent storage.
> - Ordered, graceful deployment and scaling.
> - Ordered, automated rolling updates.
>
> In the above, stable is synonymous with persistence across Pod
> (re)scheduling. If an application doesn't require any stable
> identifiers or ordered deployment, deletion, or scaling, you should
> deploy your application using a workload object that provides a set of
> stateless replicas. Deployment or ReplicaSet may be better suited to
> your stateless needs.

Comment: Ok thanks. So, to sum up (1.) StatefulSets allows you to attach a persistent disk (2.) StatefulSets are deterministic (3.) StatefulSets have consistent Pod name. Right? And one question please - can I attach persistent disk in a Deployment workload as well? And one request please - if you would elaborate more on StatefulSets (I know I can Google and read more, but it would be helpful for future visitors as well).

Comment: @pjj There's nothing special about StatfulSets with regard to persistent disks. A persistent volume can be attached to any pod, including one that was created using a regular `Deployment`. I mentioned that in the answer. I'll add some relevant documentation to my answer as well as a link to the official documentation. Hope it'll be useful.